# How can I set proxy settings programatically for JMeter without running it using command line

Tags: java, proxy, jmeter

I need to run Jmeter programmatically using Java from behind a proxy.
The problem lies in the fact I need to do it using HTTPS .

I have read the manual at: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html
I have using Jmeter for a few months now and feel comfortable with it but the problem started when I needed to switch to HTTPS.

I have tried the following: (both separately and all together)

1. Added a HTTP Request Defaults configuration with the proxy server details
2. Added the proxy server details to each HTTP Request
3. Added both https.proxyHost & https.proxyPort with the proxy server details to the system.properties file found at ...\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin

I am aware of the fact that I can run JMETER using the command line with -H -P as parameters (That works) but that isn't how I work with JMeter - I only use it programmatically therefore this is not an option.

This is a snippet describing a known JAVA bug related to my problem:

> The Java HTTP implementation has some limitations:
>   There is no control over how connections are re-used. When a connection is >released by JMeter, it may or may not be re-used by the same thread.
>   The API is best suited to single-threaded usage - various settings are defined >via system properties, and therefore apply to all connections.
>   There is a bug in the handling of HTTPS via a Proxy (the CONNECT is not handled >correctly). See Java bugs 6226610 and 6208335.
>   It does not support virtual hosts.
>   It supports only the following methods: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE and >TRACE
>   It does not support client based certificate testing with Keystore Config.

Bug link: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6226610

I've read the bug and saw that "Java SE Development Kit 8u131" would solve this problem - so I downloaded it and alas it didn't help at all.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank,

Yigal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you run JMeter from a **separate** Java program you need to pass proxy arguments to this **Java** program. There are several ways on how this could be done, check our [Java Networking and Proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) article for comprehensive information, you seem to be a fan of doing everything through the code so just add the following lines before launching a JMeter test:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","your_proxy_host");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "your_proxy_port");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost","your_proxy_host");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort","your_proxy_port");
System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts","");
```

Just in case complete code demonstrating how you can [run an existing JMeter test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/) through [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) as a proxy

```
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import java.io.File;

public class JMeterFromCode {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {


        //Define JVM Proxy Settings
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "localhost");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
        System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "localhost");
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");
        System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts", "");

        // JMeter Engine
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

        // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/tmp/jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/tmp/jmeter");
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();


        // Initialize JMeter SaveService
        SaveService.loadProperties();

        // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File("/tmp/jmeter/bin/test.jmx"));

        Summariser summer = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }

        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
        logger.setFilename("/tmp/jmeter/test.jtl");
        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);


        // Run JMeter Test
        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dmitri, It didn't work. I tried it but still no success in running the Jmeter via code behind a proxy using https. Any other ideas?

Comment: I love questions and comments like `it doesn't work` and that's it. What do you expect of me? Would you be so kind to at least turn on debug logging in JMeter and look into *jmeter.log* file and if you fail to figure out the reason out of it update your question with that information?

Comment: I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Works fine. Thank you.